# React Native Expo Pod install crashes if any dependency is related to push notifications

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods, onesignal

I have been trying to use OneSignal to recieve push notifications from my ReactNative app built with Expo. However upon building the project pod-install crashes, I tried all the solutions I found online but to no avail. I then tried switching to the firebase fcm but still the same thing happened. When I removed OneSignal/Firebase it worked without any issues.

If anyone have any ideas on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Pod crash info:

```
Using Expo modules
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `GymAppProd`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNDeviceInfo, RNGestureHandler, RNSVG, RNScreens, react-native-onesignal, and react-native-safe-area-context
Framework build type is static library
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:275: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x00000001042d8000
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0058 p:---- s:0367 e:000366 CFUNC  :attach
c:0057 p:0258 s:0361 e:000360 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:275
c:0056 p:0050 s:0341 e:000340 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:16
c:0055 p:0007 s:0338 e:000337 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:6
c:0054 p:0007 s:0335 e:000334 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0053 p:---- s:0332 e:000331 CFUNC  :require
c:0052 p:0110 s:0327 e:000326 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0051 p:0042 s:0315 e:000314 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:14 [FINISH]
c:0050 p:---- s:0312 e:000311 CFUNC  :require
c:0049 p:0110 s:0307 e:000306 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0048 p:0013 s:0295 e:000294 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0047 p:---- s:0292 e:000291 CFUNC  :require
c:0046 p:0110 s:0287 e:000286 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0045 p:0006 s:0275 e:000274 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440
c:0044 p:0045 s:0267 e:000266 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372
c:0043 p:0318 s:0256 e:000255 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365
c:0042 p:0006 s:0246 e:000245 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338
c:0041 p:0040 s:0241 e:000240 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:284
c:0040 p:0073 s:0234 e:000233 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:208
c:0039 p:0008 s:0225 e:000224 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83 [FINISH]
c:0038 p:---- s:0221 e:000220 CFUNC  :select
c:0037 p:0008 s:0217 e:000216 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83
c:0036 p:0011 s:0211 e:000210 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416
c:0035 p:0101 s:0206 e:000202 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385
c:0034 p:0051 s:0195 e:000194 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360
c:0033 p:0060 s:0187 e:000183 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165
c:0032 p:0066 s:0177 e:000172 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274 [FINISH]
c:0031 p:---- s:0168 e:000167 IFUNC 
c:0030 p:---- s:0165 e:000164 IFUNC 
c:0029 p:---- s:0162 e:000161 CFUNC  :each
c:0028 p:---- s:0159 e:000158 CFUNC  :sort_by
c:0027 p:---- s:0156 e:000155 CFUNC  :sort_by!
c:0026 p:0006 s:0152 e:000151 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267
c:0025 p:0014 s:0145 e:000144 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60
c:0024 p:0002 s:0142 e:000141 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77
c:0023 p:0005 s:0136 e:000135 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59
c:0022 p:0029 s:0129 e:000128 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754
c:0021 p:0029 s:0119 e:000118 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:288
c:0020 p:0017 s:0114 e:000113 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:210
c:0019 p:0004 s:0110 e:000109 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:168
c:0018 p:0037 s:0106 e:000105 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43
c:0017 p:0049 s:0100 e:000099 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94
c:0016 p:0041 s:0094 e:000093 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082
c:0015 p:0081 s:0090 e:000089 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64
c:0014 p:0078 s:0083 e:000082 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080
c:0013 p:0161 s:0076 e:000075 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125
c:0012 p:0011 s:0061 e:000060 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422
c:0011 p:0007 s:0056 e:000055 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244
c:0010 p:0081 s:0053 e:000052 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64
c:0009 p:0048 s:0046 e:000045 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243
c:0008 p:0009 s:0040 e:000039 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162
c:0007 p:0054 s:0036 e:000035 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52
c:0006 p:0078 s:0031 e:000030 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334
c:0005 p:0024 s:0024 e:000023 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52
c:0004 p:0378 s:0019 e:000018 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0013 e:000012 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0109 s:0008 E:002640 EVAL   /usr/local/bin/pod:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:0021e0 (none) [FINISH]
```

Package.JSON dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.13.1",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "expo": "~48.0.6",
    "expo-device": "^5.2.1",
    "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "onesignal-expo-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.4.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.8.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "rn-keyboard-sticky-view": "^1.0.4"
  },
```